# No module name theano in Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu) Version 2.

Tags: amazon-ec2, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I am currently using Amazon Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu) Version 2. It comes with major deep learning framework (such as tensorflow, theano, etc) installed.

In console, I am able to import theano, tensorflow and others.

However, when I open jupyter notebook, I can't import import them.
It gives the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4c17dd4059b8> in <module>()
----> 1 import Theano

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Theano'
```

Does anybody know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

could you try latest DLAMI v20.0 which comes with Theano 1.0.3?

Also, when you try to import theano, did you try to `source activate theano_<pythonenv>`, or switch kernel in notebook? Please note, theano is only installed in accordingly conda environment.